# Bundler invalid sequence in US-ASCII

Tags: bundler, ruby-1.9.2

Since upgrading my to using ruby 1.9.2 I've seen these kind of errors a lot using bundler (on Mac):

```
Using aasm (2.3.1) from git://github.com/rubyist/aasm.git (at master) .../specification.rb:733:
  in `gsub': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
```

My previous workaround was to not use the git source but that's not a workable workaround for all situations. From what I've read online you need to ensure that all your locales are set, but running `locale` I got this:

```
LANG="en_GB.us-ascii"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.us-ascii"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.us-ascii"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.us-ascii"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.us-ascii"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.us-ascii"
LC_TIME="en_GB.us-ascii"
LC_ALL=
```

I tried doing `export LC_ALL="en_GB.us-ascii"` to fill in that last one and running bundler again but that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may correct this error writing this

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

to your ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile or similar. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is invalid in the US-ASCII locale because it's a UTF-8 character. The most likely fix is to set your LANG to something like "en_GB.UTF-8".